# Python run mutiple ssh commands in the same session

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, paramiko

My goal is to connect to SSH with python and authenticate which i can do with Paramiko or Fabric. But i would like to keep the session open after each execution and read the input/output. With paramiko i can only run 1 command before the session is closed and i am asked to authenticate again and the session hangs. And since fabric is using the paramiko library its giving me the same issue. For example if my directory structure is like this

-home

--myfolder1

--myfolder2

I would like to execute the below commands without having to re-authenticate because the sessions closes.

```
(make connection)
run cmd: 'pwd'
output: /home
run cmd: 'cd myfolder2'
run cmd: 'pwd'
output: /home/myfolder2
```

Is this possible with any module that is out there right now? Could it be made from scratch with native python? And also is this just not possible...?

**Edit** Added code. Without the new open_session it closes and i cannot run any command. After running the first command with this i will be prompted again to authenticate and it creates an infinite loop.

**Edit2** If it closes after each command then there is no way this will work at all correct?

**edit3** If i run this on a different server and exec_command with the paramikio.SSHClient it wont ask me to reauthenticate but if i 'cd somedir' and then 'pwd' it will output that i am back in the root directory of where i created.

```
class connect:

    newconnection = ''

    def __init__(self,username,password): 
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        try:
            ssh.connect('someserver', username=username,password=password,port=22,timeout=5)
        except:
            print "Count not connect"
            sys.exit()
        self.newconnection = ssh

    def con(self):
        return self.newconnection


#This will create the connection
sshconnection = connect('someuser','somepassword').con()

while True:
    cmd = raw_input("Command to run: ")
    if cmd == "":
        break
    try:
        transport = sshconnection.get_transport()
        transport.set_keepalive(999999)
        chan = transport.open_session() 
        chan.settimeout(3)
        chan.setblocking(0)
    except:
        print "Failed to open a channel"
        chan.get_exception()
        sys.exit()

    print "running '%s'" % cmd
    stdout_data = []
    stderr_data = []
    pprint.pprint(chan)
    nbytes = 4096
    chan.settimeout(5)
    chan.get_pty()
    chan.exec_command(cmd)
    while True:
        print "Inside loop " , chan.exit_status_ready()
        time.sleep(1.2)
        if chan.recv_ready():
            print "First if"
            stdout_data.append(chan.recv(nbytes))
        if chan.recv_stderr_ready():
            print "Recv Ready"
            stderr_data.append(chan.recv_stderr(nbytes))
        if chan.exit_status_ready():
            print "Breaking"
            break

    print 'exit status: ', chan.recv_exit_status()
    print ''.join(stdout_data)
```

Comment: This is not the normal behaviour of Fabric nor Paramiko, which has no problem running multiple commands in a session. Could you post your code?

Comment: i edited my post to also include my code

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using the normal modules when you can concatenate the commands into one. Try

```
pwd ; cd myfolder2 ; pwd
```

as command. This should work but quickly becomes tedious when you have more complex commands which need arguments and horrible when the arguments contain spaces. The next step then is to copy a script with all the commands to the remote side and tell `ssh` to execute said script.

Another problem of this approach is that SSH doesn't return until all commands have executed.

Alternatively, you could build a "command server", i.e. a simple TCP server that listens for incoming connections and executes commands sent to it. It's pretty simple to write but also pretty insecure. Again, the solution is to turn the server into a (Python) script which reads commands from stdin and start that script remotely via SSH and then send commands.

Comment: Yes i would like to have the commands be based on which values are returned. If i cannot find file A then i would like ssh to execute a touch file A instead of cd A. And having a listening server for my commands is no an option as well. There are many servers and i would rather have this self contained to 1 script that i control